# Efficient way to check which records are deleted in database for updating an app's collection

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, optimization, architecture

To efficiently keep an application collection syncronized with a database without loading the same numerous records each time, I can use a database `datetime` "LastModified" fields with a table trigger. Table trigger updates the "LastModified" fields on update or insert db operations, and then I can supply the db query with the last used timestamp value to load only those records, which have timestamp values later than the parameter supplied.

The above technique helps to keep the volume of data exchange small, but there is a problem: the records, deleted in the database, remain in the application collection.

How to check, which records are deleted in database for updating an app's collection accordingly, in a way that keeps traffic data as small as possible?

Comment: could you use google analytics tracking in your server side code to track when deletions occur then use that data to update collection

Comment: In my case it is a desktop app and a database that can be installed on intranet, so, I think no.

Comment: Hom many rows do you have?

Comment: @ken2k In this case - up to 20000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table trigger that will be called on deletion. When this trigger is called it writes into another tracking table the index and the timestamp of the deletion. On your next sync you simply have to retrieve all indices to delete since the last modified date from this table.

Maybe you should take a look at the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854.aspx). It will create all the needed tables and triggers within the database to keep track of the changes made since the last synchronization. Simply follow [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928699.aspx) and afterwards take a look into your database. You should quite easily see all the added tables and triggers they use to keep track of all changes.